# Showing Settings of my Disk Encryption Policy in Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Im relatively new to the whole Graph situation.

Context : In my endpoint manager of my tenant i have created a default Disk Encryption Policy (bitlocker) over the GUI.

Now instead of doing that over and over again for my clients id like to somehow copy the settings of this policy.

Ive learned to use the Powershell SDK Module for MS Graph, that with MgDeviceManagementTemplate I can access the Bitlocker Templates/Policies and with MgDeviceManagementSetting directly the settings. Ive Save the result into a txt file (its around 4500 lines of text ID + Description)

My question now is there a possibility to access my already created policy (online they said i need the ID of the Policy but i cant seem to find this in the GUI) so that i can show me the already set Settings ?

Appreciate the help of the Community ! :)

Comment: Using Get managedDeviceEncryptionState: GET /deviceManagement/managedDeviceEncryptionStates/{managedDeviceEncryptionStateId}
you might get the policy details.

Answer (score 0):

I created one Disk Encryption Policy (bitlocker) named **`devibitlocker`** in my endpoint manager over GUI like below:

[image]

To get the above **policy ID** from MS Graph API, you can below query  in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by filtering with it's name like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/intents?$filter=displayName eq 'devibitlocker'
```

**Response:**

[image]

After getting the ID, you can fetch the **settings** of that policy by running below query like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/intents/<policyID>/settings
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the **same results** using Powershell, you can make use of below commands:

**For Policy ID:**

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "DeviceManagementConfiguration.Read.All"
Select-MgProfile beta
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.DeviceManagement 
Get-MgDeviceManagementIntent -Filter "displayName eq 'devibitlocker'"
```

**Response:**

[image]

**For Policy settings:**

```
$deviceManagementIntentId = "0f5bc8eb-6e76-4ae7-abf4-xxxxxxxxxx"
Get-MgDeviceManagementIntentSetting -DeviceManagementIntentId $deviceManagementIntentId
```

**Response:**

[image]